# PostgreSQL server running very slow at minimal work load

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

Postgres server running very slow. DB has two tables and when I run `explain analyze` for below query, taking more than `10min` and query running forever.

Tables DDL, [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7c3b8d152576cc0ff2fc9344853fdef8).

User query:

```
explain analyze select COUNT(*) as "DII_1"
  from ( select table0."individual_entity_proxy_id" as "INDIVIDUAL_ENTITY_PROXY_ID"
                                from test1 table0
                                inner join test2 table1
                                on table0."individual_entity_proxy_id" = table1."individual_entity_proxy_id"
                                where ((table0."shared_paddr_with_customer_ind" = 'N')
                                                   and (table0."profane_wrd_ind" = 'N')
                                                   and (table0."tmo_ofnsv_name_ind" = 'N')
                                                   and ((table0."last_contacted_dm_datetime" is null)
                                                   or (table0."last_contacted_dm_datetime" <  TIMESTAMP '2020-03-15  0:00:00.000000'))
                                                   and (table0."has_individual_address" = 'Y')
                                                   and (table0."has_last_name" = 'Y')
                                                   and (table0."has_first_name" = 'Y')
                                                   and (table0."direct_mail_preference" is null))
                                                   and ((table1."tax_bnkrpt_dcsd_ind" = 'N')
                                                  and (table1."cstmr_prspct_ind" = 'Prospect')
                                                  and (table1."govt_prison_ind" = 'N')) ) TXT_1;
```

`Explain Analyze`:

```
"Finalize Aggregate  (cost=3440557.89..3440557.90 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=119522.092..119522.092 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=5369032, temp read=949785 written=937509"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=3440557.16..3440557.87 rows=7 width=8) (actual time=119001.846..119559.076 rows=6 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 7"
"        Workers Launched: 5"
"        Buffers: shared hit=5369032, temp read=949785 written=937509"
"        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=3439557.16..3439557.17 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=118997.002..118997.003 rows=1 loops=6)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=5369032, temp read=949785 written=937509"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=2093187.27..3428070.55 rows=4594644 width=0) (actual time=87536.941..118613.469 rows=5394697 loops=6)"
"                    Hash Cond: (table0.individual_entity_proxy_id = table1.individual_entity_proxy_id)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=5369032, temp read=949785 written=937509"
"                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test1 table0  (cost=0.00..1130249.76 rows=4604772 width=8) (actual time=0.022..3737.959 rows=5394697 loops=6)"
"                          Filter: ((direct_mail_preference IS NULL) AND ((last_contacted_dm_datetime IS NULL) OR (last_contacted_dm_datetime < '2020-03-15 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) AND (shared_paddr_with_customer_ind = 'N'::bpchar) AND (profane_wrd_ind = 'N'::bpchar) AND (tmo_ofnsv_name_ind = 'N'::bpchar) AND (has_individual_address = 'Y'::bpchar) AND (has_last_name = 'Y'::bpchar) AND (has_first_name = 'Y'::bpchar))"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 1284863"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=972803"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=1435596.42..1435596.42 rows=40081668 width=8) (actual time=83938.784..83938.784 rows=40077727 loops=6)"
"                          Buckets: 131072  Batches: 1024  Memory Usage: 2553kB"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=4395726, temp written=818046"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on test2 table1  (cost=0.00..1435596.42 rows=40081668 width=8) (actual time=0.789..14573.245 rows=40077727 loops=6)"
"                                Filter: ((tax_bnkrpt_dcsd_ind = 'N'::bpchar) AND (govt_prison_ind = 'N'::bpchar) AND ((cstmr_prspct_ind)::text = 'Prospect'::text))"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 94756"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=4395726"
"Planning time: 3.115 ms"
"Execution time: 119559.941 ms"
```

Server config:

```
PostgreSQL v10.11
RAM: 380GB
vCore: 32
Shared_buffers: 65GB
work_mem:104857kB
maintenance_work_mem:256MB
effective_cache_size: 160GB
```

Any suggestions for optimization?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
explain analyze 
with testdata as (

    select table0."individual_entity_proxy_id" as "INDIVIDUAL_ENTITY_PROXY_ID"
    from test1 table0
    where ((table0."shared_paddr_with_customer_ind" = 'N')
        and (table0."profane_wrd_ind" = 'N')
        and (table0."tmo_ofnsv_name_ind" = 'N')
        and ((table0."last_contacted_dm_datetime" is null) or (table0."last_contacted_dm_datetime" <  TIMESTAMP '2020-03-15  0:00:00.000000'))
        and (table0."has_individual_address" = 'Y')
        and (table0."has_last_name" = 'Y')
        and (table0."has_first_name" = 'Y')
        and (table0."direct_mail_preference" is null))
    
    intersect
    
    select table1."individual_entity_proxy_id"
    from test2 table1
    where ((table1."tax_bnkrpt_dcsd_ind" = 'N')
        and (table1."cstmr_prspct_ind" = 'Prospect')
        and (table1."govt_prison_ind" = 'N')) 
)

select COUNT(*) as "DII_1"
from  testdata
```

if this not help - probably you need to create indexes, maybe change fields char to bool ('Y' -> true, 'N' -> false)